# distance between lat and long using a matrix

Tags: r, for-loop, matrix, geospatial, euclidean-distance

This is my data in a matrix. It is lat and long. I want the distance between point 1 and 2, 2 and 3, 3 and 4, etc.

```
    > mat<-as.matrix(b)
    > mat
            buoy.LON buoy.LAT
      [1,] -86.34816 43.19014
      [2,] -86.34337 43.18656
      [3,] -86.34013 43.18268
      [4,] -86.33468 43.17484
      [5,] -86.33091 43.16549
      [6,] -86.32912 43.15925
      [7,] -86.32786 43.14887

    dis<-distGeo(mat[2,],mat[3,])  #distance in meters
    did
    [1] 505.1605
```

The above formula works great, but I want to make a loop to do this quickly and I want the data to be added to the matrix.

I created this loop

```
    for (i in mat[1:169,]) {
      distGeo(mat[i,], mat[i+1,])
      }
```

but I always get a return of

```
    196
```

How can I get the for loop to work correctly, and how can I get the answers added to the matrix?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/47115848/3358272

Comment: My answer to that linked question uses `distHaversine`, but I think your use of `geosphere::distGeo` is a better (ellipsoid) calculation. (I should probably update that answer ...)

Comment: I have  a hard time following that example, when I work with it the n term is producing a problem. should I be defining n n<-numeric() or n<-1?

Comment: The answer doesn't use the `n` variable, it uses the `dplyr::n()` function ... is that what you're referring to? (Do not use any code from the question itself.)

Answer (score 0):

In Ann Arbor ey?  I'm inclined to help.

It looks like distgeo can do exactly what you want without the loop.

distGeo(p1, p2, a=6378137, f=1/298.257223563)

Arguments

p1
longitude/latitude of point(s). Can be a vector of two numbers, a matrix of 2 columns (first column is longitude, second column is latitude) or a SpatialPoints* object

So...

```
distGeo(mat)
#[1]  556.6029  505.1605  977.2286 1083.0404  708.3580 1157.7188
```

And to add that to your matrix as a column, you'll need to add a blank space for the first slot (or the last slot depending on what point you want the distance represented):

```
geodists <- distGeo(mat)
mat <- cbind(mat, dists = c(NA,geodists))
mat
#                            dists
#[1,] -86.34816 43.19014        NA
#[2,] -86.34337 43.18656  556.6029
#[3,] -86.34013 43.18268  505.1605
#[4,] -86.33468 43.17484  977.2286
#[5,] -86.33091 43.16549 1083.0404
#[6,] -86.32912 43.15925  708.3580
#[7,] -86.32786 43.14887 1157.7188
```

Go blue.

Comment: So much simpler than what I was going for, thanks a lot!