# Calculate the distance between two coordinates columns group by individuals of different ID length in R

Tags: r, coordinates, dplyr

I have locations of individuals, and the dataframe is like:

```
 ID       Lat       Lon        Distance
 1        51.5184   -0.1382
 1        51.5147   -0.1532
 2        51.5184   -0.1342
 2        51.5147   -0.1522
 2        51.5537   -0.1556
 ...      ...       ...
```

and I would like to calculate the moving distance of each individual. I am not very sure how to calculate the distances of points group by individuals in a dataframe.

I know there are some similar questions that posted before, such as this: [How can I calculate the distance between latitude and longitude along rows of columns in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47115848/how-can-i-calculate-the-distance-between-latitude-and-longitude-along-rows-of-co,but) I found our situation is a little different. When I used this function:

`mutate(Distance = 
                  c(NA, distHaversine(cbind(Lon[-n()], Lat[-n()]),
                  cbind(Lon[-1], Lat[-1]))))`

in my work, I found the error `subscript out of bounds`, and it means the ID are not of the same length. Just like my data shows, I have 2 ID:1 and 3 ID:2, which leads to this problem. I would really appreciate it if someone can tell me how to revise this function to fit my situation. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
mutate(df, Distance=distHaversine(cbind(Lon, Lat),cbind(lag(Lon),lag(Lat))))
```

Sorry, my bad - forgot `distHaversine` needs a matrix.

Comment: Thanks for your replying. But it shows me the error that: Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : Evaluation error: Wrong length for a vector, should be 2.

Comment: See edited response. This works fine with your sample data.

Comment: I have solved that problem by changing the c() to be cbind(). Thanks anyway!

Comment: That's okay! Thanks for your answer ^_^