# How to use longitude and latitude data effectively with distHarvesine()?

Tags: r, gis, geospatial, geosphere

This is mostly a follow-up question on an older post (2017) [see old post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47115848/how-can-i-calculate-the-distance-between-latitude-and-longitude-along-rows-of-co)

I have been working on a similar project and I appreciate the 2017 post for its usefulness. However, I struggle to understand and cannot find any documentation or information on what do the arguments `longitude[-n()]` and `longitude[ -1]` mean in the following context where someone calculates the distance between two geolocations.

```
distance = c(NA,
          distHaversine(cbind(longitude[-n()], latitude[-n()]),
                        cbind(longitude[  -1], latitude[  -1])))
```

I'm honestly new with geospatial analysis in R and I would really appreciate any lead on this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This statement: `cbind(longitude[-n()], latitude[-n()]` removes the last element from the vector, while this `cbind(longitude[  -1], latitude[  -1])` removes the first first element of the vector.

`distHaversine` also has a simpler syntax where if you just pass a single data.frame it will calculate the distances between the elements.  For example:

```
distHaversine(cbind(longitude, latitude)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is really helpful!